# Solve $(A- \operatorname{diag}(x) ) \,\nabla_x f(x) - c f(x)=0, \, f(0)=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, vector-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. How to solve the following differential equation

$$
(A-  \operatorname{diag}(x) ) \nabla_x f(x) - c f(x)=0,  \qquad  f(0)=1.
$$

where  $\operatorname{diag}(x)$  is a diagonal matrix with vector $x$ on the main diagonal, $A$ is some $n \times n$ matrix  and $ c \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

In the scalar case, this is easy to solve since it is a first-order linear ordinary differential equation (ODE) whose solution is given by

$$f(x) = a^{c} (a -  x)^{-c}.$$

I don't have have much experience solving matrix differential equations and would appreciate some references on this topic.

---

**Edit:** Using the approach of NN2 the above PDE can be reformulated as:
\begin{align}
(A-  \operatorname{diag}(x) )  \nabla_x g(x)=c,  \qquad g(0)=0.
\end{align}

Comment: The [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)) may be useful.

Comment: To show that there is a solution?

Comment: I don't have time to think about it. Just an idea. You are then free to try to find an use for it. May contain links to useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

My first answer isn't good. I edit the answer by taking account the comment of @loupblanc. I haven't had yet the solution.
I think we can simplify the problem by using this transformation.

From the equation, we have
$$
(A-  \operatorname{diag}(x) ) \frac{\nabla_x f(x)}{f(x)} - c=0
$$
$$ \iff
(A-  \operatorname{diag}(x) ) \nabla_x \ln{f(x)} - c=0
$$
Put $g(x) = \ln{f(x)}$
$$ \iff
(A-  \operatorname{diag}(x) ) \nabla_x g(x) - c=0
$$

Comment: $Bdiag(x)$ is not diagoanal.

Comment: @loupblanc You are right.
Perhaps, I think we could make  this transformation :
$$
(A-  \operatorname{diag}(x) ) \frac{\nabla_x f(x)}{f(x)}  =c
$$
$$ \iff
(A-  \operatorname{diag}(x) ) \nabla_x \ln{f(x)}  =c
$$

Put $g(x)=\ln{f(x)}$
$$ \iff
(A-  \operatorname{diag}(x) ) \nabla_x g(x)   =c
$$

$$ \iff
\nabla_x g(x)   = (A-  \operatorname{diag}(x) )^{-1} c
$$
The problem seems to be less difficult than before.
But after this step, I don't know how to solve the last equation.

Comment: @NN2  Do you want to modify your answer based on these observations.

Comment: @Boby I modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Nice simplification. Let me know if you have any ideas how to proceed further

Answer (score 1):

We consider the ODE in the form obtained by NN2:

$(*)$ $\nabla_xg(x)=(A-diag(x))^{-1}c=[v_1,\cdots v_n]^T$.

EDIT 1.

In general $(*)$ has no solutions except if $curl(V)=0$, that is if, for every $i<j$,

$\dfrac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}=\dfrac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}$. This NS condition reflects the fact that $\dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_jx_i}=\dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_ix_j}$.

For example, for $n=2$, the conditions on $A=[a_{i,j}],c=[c_i]$ are

$a_{1,2}c_2=a_{2,1}c_1=0.$

For $n=3$, the conditions are

$a_{2,1}c_1=a_{3,1}c_1=a_{1,2}c_2=a_{3,2}c_2=a_{1,3}c_3=a_{2,3}c_3=0$.

In particular, if, for every $i$, $c_i\not= 0$, then $A$ is diagonal (at least when $n=2,3$) and the integration of the ODE is easy.

EDIT 2. To the OP. Since I have pity on you, I'll give you a basic example that may convince you that there is no solution except for exceptional choices of $A$ and $c$.

We choose $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},c=[1,1]^T$.

The considered equation is $\Delta_x g(x)=(A-diag(x))^{-1}c$, that is

$[\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_1},\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_2}]^T=[\dfrac{-x_2-1}{x_1x_2-1},\dfrac{-x_1-1}{x_1x_2-1}]^T$. Then necessarily

$\dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_1x_2}=\dfrac{1+x_1}{(x_1x_2-1)^2}$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_2x_1}=\dfrac{1+x_2}{(x_1x_2-1)^2}$.

The last two quantities are not equal; therefore, there are no solutions $g$ that are $C^2$.

Comment: why doesn't it have solutions? Is there a reference for this?

Comment: I don't need your pity, but just an answer that is has a proper explanations and reference to why it is so.